# Is it possible to have CanvasJs Graph plotting date(xAxis) and name(yAxis)

Tags: jquery, json, canvasjs

I am not able to get CanvasJs plotting a diagnosis date on the x-Axis and name of the cancer type on the y-Axis.  I have got my JSON data coming back and is working.  Can anyone please tell me what I am not doing right please.

Here is my JSON data

```
[
    {
        "y": "follicular",
        "x": "2004-01-06"
    },
    {
        "y": "papillary",
        "x": "2010-05-04"
    }
]
```

and here is My JQUERY function

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#find").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            // the URL for the request
            url: "getDiagnosis.php",
            // the data to send (will be converted to a query string)
            data: {pnhsno: $('#search').val()},
            // whether this is a POST or GET request
            type: "GET",
            // the type of data we expect back
            dataType : "json",
            // code to run if the request succeeds;
            // the response is passed to the function
            success: function(json){

                if(json.length !=0){
                    alert(json);
                    var dataPoints = json.map(function (p) {
                         p.x = new Date(p.x);
                         return p;
                    });

                    var dp1 = []; 

                    for(var i=0; i<dataPoints.length; i++){

                        dp1.push({x:dataPoints[i].x, y:dataPoints[i].y})}
                            $("#dchart").CanvasJSChart({ //Pass chart options
                                title:{text:"Patient Diagnosis "},
                                zoomEnabled: true,
                                panEnabled: true, 
                                axisY:{valueFormatString:"DD-MM-YYYY",labelAngle:-45},

                                data: [{
                                    color:"red",
                                    type: "line",
                                    legendText:"Diagnosis", 
                                    showInLegend:true,
                                    dataPoints:dp1

                                }]
                           }); 


                }//if

                else{ $("#radioiodine").html("No Data For Radioiodine Found");}
            }//json
});
});
});
```

Comment: One issue I see is your date format string.  It should be: `valueFormatString:"YYYY-MM-DD"`

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by it not plotting?  Do you get an error?

Comment: in fact the date is seems to be plotting i.  Because I do convert the date using this function var dataPoints = json.map(function (p) {
     p.x = new Date(p.x);
     return p;
     });

Comment: no error, but nothing shows on the Y-axis and no chart drawn either

Comment: I think that might be part of your problem.  Please try simplifying and removing that map function call and instead format your date directly on the returned json, like so: `dp1.push({x:json[i].x, y:new Date(json[i].y)})}` You may need to switch to a foreach loop.

Comment: let me try it and will come back to you.. thanks

Comment: I have got no luck still

Comment: it doesn't work either

Comment: please, that would be great